# ElasticSearch Increase Term Field Limit

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Running into a problem where I exceed the number of items in the 'terms' field of an elasticsearch query. The limit is ~65k and would like to bump this for performance improvements. The elasticsearch connection is supported on a Flask app.

I've seen some references to `index.max_terms_count`, but don't know how to set this.

Thanks!

```py
some_stuff = {
        "size": 0,
        "query": {"bool": {"filter": [{'terms': {'people': my_people}}, {'terms':{'stuff', my_big_list}}]}},
        "aggs": {
            "customer_buckets": {
                "terms": {"field": "people", "size": 10000},
                "aggs": {"spending": {"sum": {"field": "net_price"}}}
            }
        }
    }

    results = await es.search(
        index='people:stuff:things',
        doc_type='interaction',
        body=some_stuff
    )
```

Comment: use can set the dynamic index setting using while updating the index as follow  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html

Comment: i dont think that using more than 65k values in a terms query can be seen as a performance improvement. Maybe with more context, someone could help you find a more elegant way to fulfill your requirements